# Azure Service Certificate limitation

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, x509certificate

As per the this MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg981929.aspx), there are two types of certificates, Management Certificate and Service Certificate. They have clearly called out in the same link that we can have 100 management certificates per account. But, didn't mention any such limitation for service certificate. Does anybody know any limitation on service certificate? I mean, maximum how many certificate I can upload in service certificate store? or any other limitations.

Actually, we want to have one or more certificates uploaded on Azure for each tenant in our application. So, we are planning to use Azure Certificate Store to store all certificates. Is this a good option or there is any better way of storing it?

Comment: Service Certificates typically map to a domain, subdomain, IP, Host Address etc you would typically list all the domains under a single certificate. If you have multiple domain with different certificates you can store them in Azure as with Management Certificates.

Comment: @Lloyd, actually we want to use the certificates in the application to do some data encryption and each tenant can provide their own certificates to do so. So, we are looking for the better solution to store all those certificates.

Comment: If you are not using them within the Azure architecture then store the private key where you can easily access it as advised by @Gaurav Mantri. Sorry private key!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/, it seems there's a hard limit of 400 service certificates per subscription. So if you have just one cloud service in your subscription, you can have 400 certificates.

Another alternative would be to save these certificates in blob storage and store the association between a certificate and a tenant in some database (SQL DB, Table Storage).

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for you response. I don't think 400 is the limit. I have run PoC where it is creating new self-signed certificate and uploading it onto Azure. I have already uploaded 500 and its still going on...I have noticed one thing is that I am able to upload only 100 certificates in single shot. I then, have to restart the application and upload another 100, and so on...

Comment: To be honest, I never tried it myself. I just searched for it and found the link. Even if there's no limit, you may want to think about your approach. Essentially you have to include certificate thumbprint in your solution's csdef file for the cloud service to install the certificate in the VM running cloud service. What that means is that each time you get a new tenant, you will have to get that tenant's certificate thumbprint, update your solution and redeploy the code.

Comment: There is hardcore limit of 400 certificates per Cloud service, not per subscription. For testing purpose, I had uploaded 400 certificates in one cloud service, then, I could upload another 100+ certificates in another service. But problem  I have noticed is that, it was not throwing any exception when you upload 401th certificate. I could upload ~700 certificates. However, system was just showing 400 certificates, it was simply ignoring 401 onward certificates. That's the reason I said I have already uploaded 500 certificates in my above comments.